# How to simplify a PHP class

Tags: php, class, subclass, simplify

I am currently working on an accounting program where different PDFs are created for several operations (offers, order confirmations, delivery notes, etc.) I have created a class "PDF" for this and created a public function for each operation. To create a delivery note I do the following:

```
$PDF = new PDF();
$PDF->createDeliveryNote();
```

However, I am now encountering a problem where the class is gradually becoming confusing. Each function has about 200 lines and the class has in total 2000. My question now: How can I make my PDF class clearer?

Comment: Perhaps you should show the class (or at least the structure), as the instantiation of it doesn't appear to be your question after all.

Comment: Maybe pass arguments to similar functions. Like $PDF->createPdf('delivery_note'); $PDF->createPdf('order_confimation');

Comment: I would prefer doing sth like `class Delivery extends PDF { function savePDF(string $filename) { ... }  }`; So each class can do what it should.

Comment: I agree with @MarkusZeller here. Have a base class and extend other "type" classes from it, abstracting commonly used functions into the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `Strategy` design pattern for that case https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Behavioral/Strategy/README.html

Something like:

```php
interface PdfOperationInterface
{
    public function create()
}
```

```php
class OrderPdfOperation implement PdfOperationInterface
{
    public function create()
    {
       // order logic
    }
}
```

```php
class OfferPdfOperation implement PdfOperationInterface
{
    public function create()
    {
       // offer logic
    }
}
```

use handler or somehow as long as can get expected operation instance, such as use *Factory* or *Pool of operations* etc

```php
class PdfOperationHandler
{
    private $operation;
    
   
    public function __construct(PdfOperationInterface $operation) {
        $this->operation = $operation;    
    }
    
    public function operate()
    {
        $this-operation->create();
    }
}
```

usage:

```php
$hander = new PdfOperationHandler(new OfferPdfOperation());

$hander->operate();
```

Comment: Thx, I will try it